# How to 301 redirect old website to a new one

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to 301 redirect my old domain say **m.oldwebsite.com** to **m.newwebsite.com**.
I believe the line below will redirect and keep the url path.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://m.newwebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

What I need is for all links on **m.oldwebsite.com** to redirect to the home page of **m.newwebsite.com**.

Forexample:

```
m.oldwebsite.com/path/to
```

to redirect to

```
m.oldwebsite.com
```

I couldn't find a clear solution for this.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly isnt working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Remove $1 parameter from rewrite and it's done, all redirect to homepage.